# Nginx failing to push web files

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, command-line-interface, webserver, nginx-config

I am trying to setup Nginx to host a React JS server. React JS works and the code runs fine - WIP -, however Nginx continues to push the 'Welcome' page instead of my files.
I have read numerous guides and Q&As, new and old, and none of them are the same nor helpful in resolving this issue.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/caseazure.com;

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name caesazure.com www.caseazure.com;
    root    /var/www/caseazure.com/public_react;
}
}

#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available (I used "sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available /etc/nginx/sites-enabled" to link the file.)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name caseazure.com www.caseazure.com;
    root /var/www/caseazure.com/public_react;
    
    index index.html index.htm index.js;
    
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

I tried rewriting the .com file, moving "include" items in the .conf file, redoing the link, writing the server information in the http section of the .conf file, and more.